# Autocomplete doesn't work every time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I've a strange problem, and I never faced it before.

I've an autocomplete about `switchName`, but sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't... I explain.

When I try my autocomplete with 1 row in my DB, the autocomplete works, but when I put all my switch (300 rows), no values appears.

I don't think there is a mistake because the SQL request works, but sometimes, my JSON has no values, that's why my autocomplete has no values.

Can you help me ?

My PHP :

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $connection = new Connection;
    $connection->connection();
    $conn = $connection->getConnection();

    $requete = $conn->prepare('SELECT switchName FROM switch
    WHERE switchName LIKE :term');
    $requete->execute(array('term' => $_GET['term'].'%'));

    $array = array();

    while($donnee = $requete->fetch()) 
    {
        $array[] = $donnee['switchName']; 
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

and my JS :

```
$(function(){ 
    $(".switchName").autocomplete({
        source: 'switchName.php',
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

and my HTML :

```
    <tr>
        <td>Switch*</td> 
        <td><input type="text" class='switchName' name="switchName"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your `echo json_encode($array);` sometimes has no values even if your `$array` is OK? Do you use character encoding other than `utf-8`? If you use different encoding, you must convert to `utf-8` first, otherwise `json_encode` will fail.

Comment: Yes, I use `utf-8` encoding, but thanks. I found the soluce, it was because my `insert` in my db was wrong. I inserted string values like this `"   switch1"` instead of `"switch1"`. The space made the autocomplete bug ^^'